# Efficient use of current date in view

Tags: sql, t-sql, date

I have a view that needs to show data for the past 60 days. Currently I have written:

`WHERE (TNP.ATimeWindowEnd > '2015-07-18 00:00:00') AND (TNP.ATimeWindowEnd < '2015-09-16 00:00:00')`

But in order to not edit this manually every time I tried using `DateAdd(Day, Datediff(Day,0, GetDate() -1), 0)` (and -61) in place of the static dates. This worked but slowed the performance of the query considerably making the view unpractical. I then moved the date function to a variable as:

`SET @ToDate = DateAdd(Day, Datediff(Day,0, GetDate() -1), 0)`

This improved speed of the query (I suspect it only runs once instead of once per line) but now I cannot use it in a view since I can't add local variables to views. Any ideas on how to get dynamic dates into a view without affecting the performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an index on `TNP(ATimeWindowEnd)`, then using a function can change the index usage.  SQL Server generally does not support the use of indexes on functions, so you can use:

```
WHERE TNP.ATimeWindowEnd >= CAST(DATEADD(day, -60, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) as DATE)
```

All the computation is done on the `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.  The time component is removed by the `CAST()`.

If you are using an older version of SQL Server, then you need to use the `DATEADD()` trick to remove the time component.

Comment: Thanks a ton. Reduced time again and got me the correct rows as well :) I don't have an index on ATimeWindowEnd actually, but that is a long story ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Can you use below in the view? Please check.

```
WHERE TNP.ATimeWindowEnd > DATEADD(day, -60, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

Edit: Replaced `<` with `>`

Comment: Probblem with that is that it won't be running from midnight to midnight then. If I run `SELECT DATEADD(day,-60,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)` now I get 2015-07-19 12:41:45.137 so my query won't be returning full days.